# The preview of the hyperlink on the message sent from Bot to Teams is not displayed

Tags: python, botframework

The following tag information is added to the character string of the message sent from Bot to Teams client.

`<a href='target URL'>'anchor text'</a>`

It works as a hyperlink in chat,
The link preview is not displayed on the message.
Is there any notation for displaying a preview on a message sent by a bot?
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you do see link previews in messages sent by the user? Can you show screenshots of what you're talking about? Do you have messaging extensions installed that perform link unfurling? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't have the messaging extensions installed so I will try it.

Comment: I was asking about your expectations. We need to know what you want to happen in order to help you. What sort of "preview" do you expect to be displayed? Please show us with actual images.

Comment: I've added an image of the message that shows the preview I want the bot to send to the user.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling#handle-the-composeextensionquerylink-invoke) how link unfurling is handled in messaging extensions, where a card is generated for a user to send to other users. Your bot can similarly create a card to send to the user. A [thumbnail card](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#thumbnail-card) would make sense in your case. Have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/06.using-cards) to see how to work with cards.